# How do I stringify JSON with a specific path?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have used `JSON.stringify();` in the past, but I can't seem to specify a specific path for my JSON. When I run this code:

```
socket.emit('m', {
    author = res.hits.['_source'].author;
    description: "<td>" + JSON.stringify(author) + "</td>",
});
```

I get the following error:

```
author = res.hits.['_source'].author;
                  ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
```

Comment: `author = res.hits['_source'].author`

Comment: Try `res.hits['_source'].author`

Comment: Whats the result of `author` at the time of `JSON.stringify(author)`?

Comment: As others have said, you should remove the `.` before the brackets

Comment: That was easier than I thought, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the JSON.stringify() is causing the problem.

Looks like you are mixing up 2 notation styles, the dot notation and bracket notation. If you remove the dot in front of the ['_source'] it should work I think.

```
author = res.hits['_source'].author;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `res` object which looks similar to this?

```
res =  { hits: { _source: { author: 'xyz'}}};
```

If yes then you have are doing it incorrectly to reach `author` you need to do it like this

```
author = res.hits['_source'].author;
```